# POSTing xml to Google Checkout

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml, google-checkout

I'm experimenting with using Google Checkout and am having a problem posting to the checkout server.  Here is my code:

```
XNamespace ns = XNamespace.Get("http://checkout.google.com/schema/2");

XDocument cart = new XDocument();
XElement rootElement = new XElement(ns + "checkout-shopping-cart",
    new XElement("shopping-cart",
        new XElement("items",
            new XElement("item",
                new XElement("item-name", "doodad"),
                new XElement("item-description", "Description for the doodad"),
                new XElement("unit-price", 9.99, new XAttribute("currency", "GBP")),
                new XElement("quantity", 1)
            )
         )
    )
);

cart.Add(rootElement);

string authKey = "111222333444:NOTAREALKEY";
authKey = EncodeToBase64(authKey);

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://checkout.google.com/cws/v2/Merchant/111222333444/merchantCheckout");

request.Method = "POST";
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(cart.ToString());
request.ContentType = "application/xml; charset=UTF-8";
request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
request.Headers.Add("Authorization: Basic " + authKey);
request.Accept = "application/xml; charset=UTF-8";

Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
dataStream.Close();

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse(); // Exception here!
dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
string responseText = reader.ReadToEnd();

reader.Close();
dataStream.Close();
response.Close();
```

When I call GetResponse(), I get a `(400) Bad Request`.

Any assistance on this would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your XML looks broken as Jon Skeet points out :-). In order to further aid debugging - there may be more information about the error in the response. `WebException` has a `Response` object that might have a more detailed error message that can be read by calling its `GetResponseStream()` method.

Comment: Aha! Thank you, the error in the WebException's Response did indeed point me in the right direction. (Although it may as well have said 'Dave, you're being an idiot!').  I was using a sandbox merchant ID, but the live url.  Thanks ever so much for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Not knowing anything about the Google Checkout API, are you sure you don't need the namespace on *each* of those elements?

```
XElement rootElement = new XElement(ns + "checkout-shopping-cart",
    new XElement(ns + "shopping-cart"),
        new XElement(ns + "items",
                     // etc
```

That's certainly what the [Checkout API guide](http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_XML_API.html#checkout_api) suggests to me - note that "xmlns=..." means that's the namespace for this element and all descendant elements unless otherwise specified.

Comment: I dont think so, according to the API docs: http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_XML_API.html#checkout_integration_options

Comment: @DavidGouge: I think you've missed the fact that it's xmlns="..." rather than xmlns:foo="...".

Comment: Not sure I follow, but having double checked the xml I'm generating, it seems I'm getting a blank namespace on the children of the root element.  Wonder if that is causing the problems.

<checkout-shopping-cart xmlns="http://checkout.google.com/schema/2">
  <shopping-cart xmlns="" />
  <items xmlns="">
    <item>
      <item-name>doodad</item-name>
      <item-description>Description for the doodad</item-description>
      <unit-price currency="GBP">9.99</unit-price>
      <quantity>1</quantity>
    </item>
  </items>
</checkout-shopping-cart>

Comment: @DavidGouge: Yes, that's because you haven't specified a namespace - it's effectively "undoing" the xmlns="..." from the parent. Have you tried my suggestion?

Comment: Ok, I've added the 'ns + ' to each element (and also fixed a bug that was creating an empty 'shopping-cart' element) but I get the same Bad Request error.  I'm starting to think that it's not the content of the post that's the problem as I would expect *a* response from google telling me it's rubbish.

Comment: The fact that it's returning you "bad request" *is* telling you it's rubbish. That's the point of the bad request status code. Not including the namespaces may well not be the *only* problem, but I think it was *a* problem.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help.  Seems it was a combination of the xml being incorrect and me using a sandbox merchant ID with the live url.  Thanks very much for the help and the push in the right direction. :D

Answer (score 0):

You still can read response message, if exception is WebException. This will give you more information on what's wrong:

```
try {
   response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
}
catch (WebException ex1) {
   response = ex1.Response();
}
```